# How should we define $E \subset F$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

My professor writes

Let E and F be 2 subsets of the set U,
$$E\cap F := \text{ }\{u\in U | u \in F \text{ and }  u \in E \}$$

He then asks to define $E\subset F$. I tried to define it this way:

$$E\subset F := \text{ }\{u\in F | u \in E\}$$
So if E is a subset of F, then it returns E, if not, it returns an empty set.
However, this isn't true for when E is an empty set. What is the correct way to define $E\subset F$?

Comment: I think that $E\subset F$ should be something that is either true or false. I think your teacher wants you to use "intersection" to decide this. Can you come up with a relation between $E\cap F$ and $E$ and/or $F$ that is true precisely when $E$ is a subset of $F$?

Comment: that $E\cap F = E$ iff $E \subset F$ ?

Comment: That's what I think your professor was getting at. The question seems a little bit open-ended, so I don't think I can say "yes, you're 100% right", but that's what I'd come up with. Can you go ask them "Hey, is this what you were looking for?"?

Answer (score 4):

$E\subset F$ is not a set like $E\cap F$. Though the two expressions look strikingly similar, they are very different. $E\cap F$ is a notation to describe all of the things that are in the set $E$ and also in the set $F$.

On the other hand, $E \subset F$ is a *logical statement*. It means that all of the elements of $E$ are also elements of $F$.

This is like of like the difference between the expressions $x+1$ and $x<1$. One is just a number, the other is a *statement* containing information.

If you want to talk about "returning", you could say $E\subset F$ returns "true" when $E$ is totally contained in $F$, and returns "false" otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

In terms of the logical operators and concepts involved, you can define it this way:
\begin{align*}
E\subset F & \Longleftrightarrow (\forall x\in U)(x\in E\to x\in F).
\end{align*}

Comment: Use `\implies`, not `\to` to indicate logical implication.

Comment: @K.defaoite I guess there is no need to do so. That is because the free variable $x$ is quantified, which means it is in fact an implication.